# Clojure ISeq from Scala classes

Tags: scala, clojure

I have a bunch of Scala classes (like Lift's Box, Scala's Option, etc.) that I'd like to
use in Clojure as a Clojure ISeq.

How do I tell Clojure how to make these classes into an ISeq so that all the various sequence
related functions "just work"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build on Arthur's answer, you can provide a generic wrapper class in Scala along these lines:

```
class WrapCollection(repr: TraversableOnce[_]) extends clojure.lang.Seqable { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

If the classes implement the `Iterable` interface then you can just call `seq` on them to get a seqeuence. Most of the functions in the sequence library will do this for you though so in almost all normal cases you can just pass them to seq functions like `first` and `count` as is.

Comment: The first part of this is true and good advice, but you absolutely cannot extend Seqable to an already-defined class, as it is an interface, not a protocol.

Comment: Isn't this only the case for `java.lang.Iterable`?  Scala collections (let alone `Option` or `Box`) do not, instead mixing in (or being implicitly converted to) `scala.collection.TraversableOnce`, `scala.collection.TraversableLike`, and/or their subtraits.

Comment: s/java.lang/java.util/ in my previous comment.  :/